# Typescript fetch data from server and loading state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am pretty new to typescript and am not sure how to best go about this rather common scenario. I fetch data and pass it into a template component as such:

```
const ProfilePage: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { data, isDataLoading } = useProfileData();

  return (
    <ProfileTemplate
      data={!isDataLoading && data}
    />
  );
};
```

This is the `ProfileTemplate` component

```
import { profile_data, Maybe } from '../api-client';

type ProfileProps = {
  data: Maybe<profile_data>;
}

export const ProfileTemplate: FC<ProfileProps> = ({ data }): JSX.Element => {
  ...
  <StaticField label="First Name" text={data.first_name} />
  <StaticField label="Last Name" text={data.last_name} />
  ...
}
```

Calling it as such results in Type `'false | Maybe<profile>' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<profile>'.` I can remove the conditional which checks `isDataLoading` first, however I then get `object is possibly null` errors in my `<StaticField>` components.

`first_name` and `last_name` can be null or empty in the database. Although I realize that's not what's causing the `object is possibly null` errors, rather an empty `profile_data` object, when no data has been returned from the server yet.

How should I best handle this situation?

```
My `<StaticField>` component looks like so: interface Props {
  label: string;
  text?: Maybe<string>;
}

export const StaticField: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ label, text }): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Text color="gray.BlackCoral" className={classes.label}>
        {label}
      </Text>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is in your `useProfileData`?

Answer (score 1):

You should handle like this to make sure `ProfileTemplate` always has `data`

```
{
  !isDataLoading && <ProfileTemplate data={data} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is less than ideal because the function needs to return something. But thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This line here is the problem

```
  data={!isDataLoading && data}
```

I suggest you refactor your code to have conditional render like so

```
if (isDataLoading || !data) {
    return null
}
return (
    <ProfileTemplate data={data}/>
);
```

However you can simply replace the data prop with a ternary
It is always good practice to extract into constants

```
const data = isDataLoading ? data : undefined;
return (
    <ProfileTemplate data={data}/>
);
```

The second option still does not account for what should be rendered when you have data undefined
So you would need a render of null inside ProfileTemplate

Comment: Thanks a lot! Definitely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, `Maybe` seems to have been defined like `type Maybe<T> = T | null`.

So, since you expect `data` to be either present or `null`, you can change your consumption logic to

```
<ProfileTemplate
  data={isDataLoading ? null : data}
/>
```

This will get rid of the error `'false | Maybe<profile>' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<profile>'.`. This error shows up because in your existing code `!isDataLoading && data` can either evaluate to `false` or whatever the type of `data` is.

Secondly, since `data` can be `null`, using it to access `data.first_name` can be a problem. That's what TypeScript is trying to tell you. One way to "fix" it would be to use the optional chaining `data?.first_name` to tell the compiler that you'll access `first_name` iff `data` is defined.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I added optional chaining... And then in my <StaticField> component, should I have `text` typed as `Maybe<string>`? It errors out with just `string`, but is there any reason to not use `Maybe` in that case?